# Cannot Use mysql from Guest Account Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, mysql, guest-session, edubuntu

I have to install ubuntu in a school's computer lab. I am using an Administrator Account for Admin purposes and enabling guest account for students so that no student can make permanent changes. 
mysql is easily accessible from 'administrator' account (I have made a [Guest Account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RL4ZN.png) so that a common replica can be transferred to all PCs)

Problem is while accessing mysql using command `mysql -u guest -p` from Guest Account, I am getting the error

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can’t connect to local MySQL server through socket ‘/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock’ (2)

Please help.

Comment: Well it depends on what you want the guest to do? Have acess to database, table etc... What exactly should they be doing?

Comment: anything, students are to learn mysql. So all access is to be given. But not to the system. I don't want to repair the PCs every now and then because students tend to change system settings often.

Comment: Are your students going to each have a guest account or all will use one guest account?

Comment: I would recommend to use kickstart installation (https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/i386/ch04s06.html). I guess you have all identical computers, so you can use one installation for all. In that way, it is easy to reinstall the computers quickly anytime. I have experience with RedHat/CentOS. Kickstart there is very flexible. You can put scripts in kickstart to finalize the installation that computer is ready to be used right after installation.

Comment: What about rbash (https://www.tecmint.com/rbash-a-restricted-bash-shell-explained-with-practical-examples/)?

Comment: You probably need to tweak `/etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/lightdm`.

Comment: @George there 'n' PCs in the lab one PC per student. One guest account per PC. That's it.

Comment: @nobody problem is not the installation, problem is how to use/access mysql through built-in guest account.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson how ?? please guide.

Comment: @V A Thomas I know the problem is the access. However, if you do not manage to sort out the rights and give to much access rights to students, you may often end up with a computer that needs a fresh install.

Comment: @nobody giving them access to system will create lot many problems for me, I'll have to restore multiple systems on weekly basis.